# iOS in app photos not recovered from iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

My application behaves abnormally. Saves images in this way:

```
NSData *pngData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0);
NSString *filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:imageName];
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

- (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}
```

However, after taking a iphone backup and restoring it. The application has all the data, but the picture is not recovered. What could be the reason?

Comment: NSData *pngData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0); instead of self it should be image object. can you tell me what's self here?

Comment: I'm sorry I did not mention that these methods are in the category UIImage, so self = UIImage